# Making Quiz App in Android with Radio Buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making a Quizz App for Android with 10 Questions, all of them with 4 Radio Buttons, and one button at the end to show the score. The problem is when I choose the correct answer it gives 5 points, but if I check another radio button the points will stay 5 and if I press again it sums 5. What is the best way to code this?

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.android.quizproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int points = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void firstRadioButtons (View view){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.questionOneA:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
                break;
        case R.id.questionOneB:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
                break;
        case R.id.questionOneC:
            if (checked)
                points += 5;
                break;
        case R.id.questionOneD:
            if (checked)
                points += 0;
                break;
    }

}

public void showScore (View view) {
    TextView scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    scoreTextView.setText(" " + points);
}
```

}

Comment: The way you phrased the question is a little confusing. The code you show adds 5 points if the correct option (C) is clicked and does nothing if another option is clicked. Is this not the intended behaviour? Or are you just asking for the best way to implement this?

Comment: Sorry,my English is the worst!
The problem is, when I select the correct one it adds 5 points, if I switch to A, B or D it sums 0 but never subtracts the 5 points given when chose C, and If I choose C again It will add points, total 10 points.

Comment: No worries on the English. You're doing well to get this far! How are the questions laid out? Are all ten questions on one page, or is there a "next" button to go between questions? If there is a button, don't add/subtract points until that is selected. If they are on one page, check all of the questions when the score button is pressed at the end, not when an option is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a counter vvariable which checks if the question has been previousy answered or not. Modify part of your code to this

```
public void firstRadioButtons (View view){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    int count=0;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.questionOneA:
            if (checked)
                {
            if(count!=0){
                points-=5;
                count=0;
                }
                }
                break;
        case R.id.questionOneB:
            if (checked)
                {
            if(count!=0){
                points-=5;
                count=0;
                }
                }
                break;
        case R.id.questionOneC:
            if (checked){
                points += 5;
                count+=1;}
                break;
        case R.id.questionOneD:
            if (checked)
                {
            if(count!=0){
                points-=5;
                count=0;
                }
                }
                break;
    }

}
```

Comment: It'd be easier to store a boolean to add/subtract, then do all that points stuff at the very end of the method

Comment: It's actually a good ideia, thanks for your suggestion, I'm really aprecciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way you described it, it's common sense. If you click the right answer once, it will set it to 5, but if you press any other it will add 0 to it.

In general, it will print out 5 since you got the answer correct once, and the other questions are set to 0. There's really nothing to fix here, it's kind of common sense that your variable wouldn't read other than 5. Just like Abhriya said, you could add a counter increment value as done in ( her / his ) example.